# JS: Displaying quick search results on a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused how I can achieve this.

Basically I have this form on my home page that filters listed results

```
<form>
    <select class="form-control select-box">
        <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
        <?php
            while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <button href="search.php">Search</button>
</form>
```

As you can see it is using PHP and lists results through MySQL. This form is on the front page. As you can see the button element is only linking to the search.php page.

I have an identical form on my search.php page although when a user clicks the button element the option they selected has been refreshed, how do I load the page with the option that the user selected and save it until the user presses a reset button or changes them manually?

Any code examples would be great I am guessing this would be a cookie?

Comment: Shouldn't your `href` be the `action` of the `form`? I mean something like `<form action='search.php'>...</form>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<select name ="select-box-1" lass="form-control select-box">
                 <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                 {
                 echo '
                 <option value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
             </select>
             <button type = "submit" >Search</button>
</form>
```

I have changed few things in your html so that I can get selected options on search.php.

```
1. <form action="search.php" method="get">
```

This will submit your form to search.php using GET method.

```
2. <button type = "submit" >
```

Changed your button type to submit so that your form gets submitted to the action specified in form action.

If you want the selected values preselected than on your search.php do following modification:

```
<select class="form-control select-box">
         <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
         <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         {
            echo '<option value="'.$make["Make"].'" ' . (($make["Make"] == $_GET["select-box-1"])? "selected=selected":'') .'>'.$make["Make"].'</option>';
         } ?>
</select>
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt although I get a parse error :(

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'select' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: echo '<option value="'.$make["Make"].'" ' . (($make["Make"] == $_GET["select-box-1"])? "selected=selected":'') .'>'.$make["Make"].'</option>';

Try this. Also updated in the answer. Thanks